# Mifare Classic with AES diversified key

Tags: cryptography, aes, smartcard, mifare

Could anyone explain to me the vulnerability of Mifare Classic with AES-128 bit key diversification? Do Mifare Classic chips protect against cloning?

Comment: If my understanding was correct it is vulnerable even without knowing the master key, so I guess MiFare is a loss cryptographically speaking. After reverse engineering the chip researchers found out that the proprietary algorithms were vulnerable. You should try to upgrade to DESFire (as a minimum). PS I did not personally verify this information, but it was pretty big news in NL because the public transport chip card is using both MiFare Ultra-lite & classic.

Comment: AES-128 bit key diversification *in itself* is not likely to be vulnerable. MiFare chips do protect against cloning as the card specific keys must be present. Of course, since MiFare itself is vulnerable, the anti-cloning part is likely to be affected.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Mifare Classic does not use AES encription algorithm. NXP decided to use Crypto-1 instead. Unfortunately they made a serious mistake with implementation of the internal Random Number Generator so that it is possible to predict first 12 bits of total 48 bits of session key. The rest can be cracked by brute force and air traffic analyses within a reasonable period of time.

NXP strongly advises to not use Mifare Classic in new projects. Instead, it is recomended to use UltralightC or DesFire EV1. Those cards can communicate using AES encription (DES, 3DES, 3KDES are also avaliable). Until now, DesFire EV1 has not been cracked. Previous versions of DesFire were broken in research labs by power consumption analyses. EV1 is protected against this method of attack.

Regarding the cloning - it is not possible to copy the contents of a card and paste it directly to another one, as each card have different UID that cannot be altered, so it will not be an exact copy. If the attacked system is checking UID, then the cloned card will not work. But it is possible to build device which will simulate a Mifare card (in this case it is possible to set any UID).

Comment: There exist unlicensed clones of MIFARE Classic that even allow programming of the UID, making perfect copying of a card possible.

Comment: Thanks for information. I didn't know about it.

Comment: Regarding "UltralightC ... can communicate using AES encription(sic)"... This isn't true. The only cryptographic operation the Ultralight C card supports is mutual authentication (using a handshake based on 2K3DES). The card does not support any session encryption, using AES, 3DES, or otherwise. However, as long as session security for anything other than card/reader authentication isn't important for your application, the recommendation of the Ultralight C card as an alternative to Mifare Classic is still sound.